# Jackson converting java object primitive properties as optional in json string

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am new in Spring Boot and I would like to send a request to a 3rd party API. I have the below post parameters in JSON to be used as the *@RequestBody*;

{
     "startDate" : "2015-07-01",
      "endDate" : "2015-10-01",
      "userId" : 1,
      "type" : 1,
   }

**OR**

{
"startDate" : "2015-07-01",
"endDate" : "2015-10-01"
}

```
public class ReportRequest {

@NotNull
private String startDate;

@NotNull
private String endDate;

private int userId;

private int type;

//getters and setters
```

I used *@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY* on the class and field level. I also tried *NON_NULL* to ignore the 'userId' and 'type' but I still have them in the @RequestBody object.

```
@PostMapping(value="/getData", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getReport(@Valid @RequestBody ReportRequest reportRequest){
```

There is no problem when I send the request with all the JSON properties. However, when I just send the mandatory data, the 'userId' and the 'type' are automatically set to 0.

I know using the *Optional* is not the best practice. I could not figure out a way of creating the request Object with the 2 optional JSON request data. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `Integer` instead of `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userId` and `type` are of `int` which is primitive and default value is `0` and `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL` will only ignore properties with null values, so make `userId` and `type` as `Integer` type so that it's default value is `null` and jackson can exclude them

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ReportRequest {

  @NotNull
  private String startDate;

  @NotNull
  private String endDate;

  private Integer userId;

  private Integer type;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I did what you suggested and it worked.